# Change the content of a div in a register wizard in function of in which step the user is

Tags: javascript, html

I have a register wizard. When the numbers of the left div are clicked, they show a different content in the right div. I need when I click the button "saltar este paso" (next step), the content of the right div change and show the content of the next step. So, when the button is clicked, i need a javascript function who guess in what step we are and show the content of the next step. How can I do this?

This is the function I use to change the content of the div in the right side when a button of the left side is clicked.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13616690/1.png]

```
function changeContentStep(id_number,content_number, id_title, content_title,   
                           id_description, content_description)

 {


    var container_number = document.getElementById(id_number);
    var container_title = document.getElementById(id_title);
    var container_description = document.getElementById(id_description);

    container_number.innerHTML = content_number;
    container_title.innerHTML = content_title;
    container_description.innerHTML = content_description;

}
```

Comment: Show more of your code. Use JSFiddle.